# How eclipse executes a Java application?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a very simple `.java` file in Eclipse Java Project that creates a `.txt` file.

```
package mproject.assgn.q12;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ColumnPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getInputFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }

    private static File getInputFile() {

        String content = "110\t100\t255\t122\n"
                + "100\t109\t180\t111\n"
                + "22\t101\t122\t110\n"
                + "211\t122\t177\t101";

        File file = new File("file2.txt");
        try {

            if(!file.exists()){

            System.out.println("Creating Input File since it does'nt exist");
            file.createNewFile();

            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            bw.write(content);
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();

            return file;
        }

        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Error during File I/O");
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

What I want to know is why the file that is created is found under `/projectFolder/`, while the .java resides in `/projectName/src` and the class file resides in `/projectFolder/bin`. **Shouldn't the text file be created under the /bin folder where the .class file resides ?**

How does eclipse execute the .java file when we select "`Run As Java Application`" ?

Does it compile it to a jar and then execute it ?

Answer (score 2):

**Why the text file is not under /bin**
Eclipse creates hidden by default project files - .project. The directory where this file is created is considered the root directory for the project. When using relative file paths, they are always resolved against the project root.

**How does Eclipse run the application**

Eclipse compiles the classes under /bin (unless specified otherwise) and executes the class with `main` method. Considering you have more than one class with a main method, you have to choose after selecting `Run As Java Application`.

Also, a side note regarding the jar files - those are just archives containing classes and other files. When executing a jar file, you are basically executing the main method of the main class, declared in the `META-INF/Manifest.mf` file.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a file with the `java.io.File` with the `String` constructor like that, the path is relative to the current working directory from which the application is run. When you select **Run As** > **Java Application** in Eclipse, the default working directory is the project root, which explains why your file is created there.

You can easily change the working directory for an application you launch from Eclipse: open the **Run Configurations** (or **Debug Configurations**) dialog (from either the toolbar buttons for Run/Debug or the **Run** menu), select the launch configuration for your application, then go to the **Arguments** tab. Near the bottom you'll see the section to select a *Working directory*.